# How to add a class in jQuery when page is scrolled AND clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a HTML website where when the page is scrolled, depending on which section is being viewed, JavaScript/jQuery will apply/remove classnames from `a` links

I have achieved this already. And when the `a` is clicked, it will go to that section of the page, but the problem is that it will not apply the classname to that `a` unless the page is scrolled.

Please ask for more clarification if you need it.

-EDIT: The scrolling part works, but try clicking on the links. It changes the class (highlights) some, but not all of them-

Many thanks, and all help is appreciated.

Code (I would recommend opening it in fullscreen/full page):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .sidebar a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .sidebar a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidebar .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    .openbtn {
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #111;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .openbtn:hover {
      background-color: #444;
    }
    
    #main {
      transition: margin-left .5s;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidebar {
        padding-top: 15px;
      }
      .sidebar a {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    
    .active {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar" style="width: 250px;">

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closeBTN" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()" style="display: none;">✕</a>
    <div class="active">
      <a onclick="addTHIS()" href="#Home">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <a onclick="addTHIS()" href="#AboutUs">Services</a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <a onclick="addTHIS()" href="#Images">Clients</a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <a onclick="addTHIS()" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="main" style="margin-left: 250px;">
    <button class="openbtn" id="openBTN" onclick="openNav()" style="display: none;">☰  Open Sidebar</button>
    <section class="scrollspy" id="Home">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique
        sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa.
        Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse
        potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

      <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed
        non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices
        enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

      <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean
        laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>



    </section>

    <section class="scrollspy" id="AboutUs">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique
        sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa.
        Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse
        potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

      <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed
        non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices
        enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

      <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean
        laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>


    </section>

    <section class="scrollspy" id="Images">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique
        sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa.
        Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse
        potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

      <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed
        non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices
        enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

      <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean
        laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>


    </section>

    <section class="scrollspy" id="Contact">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique
        sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa.
        Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse
        potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

      <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed
        non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices
        enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

      <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean
        laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>


    </section>

  </div>
  <script>
    function myFunction(x) {
      if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        document.getElementById("closeBTN").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("openBTN").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("openBTN").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("closeBTN").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
      }
    }

    var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
    myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
    x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
  </script>
  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
      var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var elems = $('.scrollspy');
      elems.each(function(index) {
        var elemTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(this).height();
        if (currentTop >= elemTop && currentTop <= elemBottom) {
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id + '"]');
          navElem.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
      })
    });

    function addTHIS() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id + '"]');
      navElem.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you had errors referring to elements. I made you the following code for clicking on links:

```
$('.sidebar a').click(function() {   
   $('.sidebar a').closest('div').removeClass('active');               
   $(this).closest('div').addClass('active');     
});
```

Run snippet:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
      if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        document.getElementById("closeBTN").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("openBTN").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("openBTN").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("closeBTN").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
      }
    }

    var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
    myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
    x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes

    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
      var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var elems = $('.scrollspy');
      elems.each(function(index) {
        var elemTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(this).height();
        if (currentTop >= elemTop && currentTop <= elemBottom) {
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id + '"]');
          navElem.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
      })
    });
    
    
    $('.sidebar a').click(function() {   
      $('.sidebar a').closest('div').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('div').addClass('active');     
    });
```

```css
body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .sidebar a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .sidebar a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidebar .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    .openbtn {
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #111;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .openbtn:hover {
      background-color: #444;
    }
    
    #main {
      transition: margin-left .5s;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidebar {
        padding-top: 15px;
      }
      .sidebar a {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    
    .active {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar" style="width: 250px;">

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closeBTN" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()" style="display: none;">✕</a>
    <div class="active">
      <a href="#Home">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <a href="#AboutUs">Services</a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <a href="#Images">Clients</a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="main" style="margin-left: 250px;">
    <button class="openbtn" id="openBTN" onclick="openNav()" style="display: none;">☰  Open Sidebar</button>
    <section class="scrollspy" id="Home">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique
        sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa.
        Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse
        potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

      <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed
        non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices
        enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

      <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean
        laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>



    </section>

    <section class="scrollspy" id="AboutUs">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique
        sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa.
        Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse
        potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

      <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed
        non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices
        enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

      <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean
        laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>


    </section>

    <section class="scrollspy" id="Images">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique
        sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa.
        Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse
        potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

      <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed
        non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices
        enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

      <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean
        laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>


    </section>

    <section class="scrollspy" id="Contact">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
        porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique
        sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa.
        Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse
        potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

      <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed
        non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices
        enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

      <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean
        laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>


    </section>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.

Comment: @HTMLJSCSS, Did my answer help you?

Comment: `$('.sidebar div.active').removeClass('active')` is another approach

Comment: @Taplar, this expression can actually be done in different ways. My version is also relevant. Will work well in both cases.